# Yet Another Notice: Undefined index Question

Tags: php, switch-statement

I keep getting

> Notice: Undefined index: action

When I use the following code. I use it to see which page is required. Anyway to sort this out? I know you're not supposed to just include files from user input (without checking the input first), but this switch statement only works if action is set to view or blah, otherwise it just shows the main page.

?action=view or ?action=blah

```
switch ($_GET['action']) 
{
    case 'view':
         echo "We are in view";
        require FORUM_ROOT . 'view2.php';
    break;

    case 'blah':
      echo "We are in blah";
    break;

    default:
        "This is default";
        require FORUM_ROOT . 'main.php';
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rewrite your code in this way:

```
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null;

switch ($action) { ... }
```

Comment: This is proper error handling! Ternary ops (What he is doing on the first line) are not that obvious for people who have never seen them, but are a great tool to have in the box of tricks as it's VERY POWERFUL. +1

Comment: @Mark Tomlin: "are not that obvious for people who have never seen them" --- well, it is a great reason to learn something new for them then ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you are attempting to use $_GET['action'] when it doesn't exist. Like for instance, when you go to the page without passing page.html?action=xxx

Answer (score 0):

You're using an array element without checking whether it exists. You should make sure that your code does not try to read `$_GET['action']` when that might not be defined.

You can do this in a way that doesn't require altering your `switch` logic, by giving `$_GET['action']` a defined (but "empty") value if `action` wasn't given in the query string:

```
if (!isset($_GET['action']))
    $_GET['action'] = null;

switch ($_GET['action']) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a specific syntax construct `@` for ignoring notices when they are provably redundant.

```
switch (@$_GET['action']) {
```

The isset ternary is used as microoptimization workaround, but otherwise has no practical benefit in your case.

Comment: Errors are a good thing, they let you know when something is wrong. simply ignoring them is not acceptable when you have the possibility of dealing with the situation in other ways. -1

Comment: @MarkTomlin: Where did I say to ignore errors? And do you actually realize that using isset() suppresses the notice alike?

Comment: I feel this is not the correct way to handle this notice. Yes it's just a notice, but the idea of using this syntax in the case where it can be handled without suppression, that route _should_ be taken. Teaching someone who is fairly new to programming how to suppress can be dangerous, because he might feel it's acceptable in other cases, where really it should be used as a last resort.

Comment: @MarkTomlin. Deciding on a syntax construct based on perception or memes is not a well-informed approach. Here is a *specific* example where it is the proper option. I think you're one of the people who don't comprehend that isset?: is just syntactic salt with the same intention.

Comment: My understanding of the "Error Control Operator", as it's called in the PHP manual, is that placed in uneducated hands can cause more harm then good. I know it does the same thing as the ternary expression in this example, but the use of the "Error Control Operator" should only be used as a last resort. Especially to someone who is new, because it's use can cause more harm then good.

Comment: You already said that. It doesn't get less fictional from mentioning it more often though. I'm sure you want to attribute your opinion to some other cases now, but that still doesn't explain the perceived problem here. And I'm certain it's not more educative to badtalk a solution to OPs actual issue just because it doesn't meet cargo cult programming guidelines. -- Mind you, I had those discussions quite a lot. But never ever did anyone explain the reasoning beyond hearsay.

Comment: Yeah, I've made my point, but you don't want to accept it's premise. Well, I appreciated the discussion anyway. I'm just worried that he is going to start using Error Suppression everywhere causing more harm then good. Your right The OP's question is answered with your reply, but the answer might provide more harm then good.

Comment: Your concern is unwarranted. This specific syntax construct doesn't lend itself to overuse, nor was it advertised as nonplusultra. There are far worse practices mentioned in the PHP manual and w3schools without guidance (e.g. mysql_query). It's more likely that he'll adopt more unreadable code now due to syntax aversion.

Comment: "Your concern is unwarranted." Yeah, that's coming over quite clear.